# How do you exclude a column from appearing in results?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This query returns quarterly sales, but I'd like to hide the order_date column from appearing in results. order_date is just used to determine if the item is purchased during the quarter.

```
SELECT item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_type, item.item_price, SUM(orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Quantity Ordered', 
SUM(item.item_price*orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Total Sales Per Item', orders.order_date FROM item 
JOIN orderdetail ON item.item_id = orderdetail.item_id 
JOIN orders ON orderdetail.order_id = orders.order_id
GROUP BY item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_price, item.item_type
HAVING order_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
ORDER BY item.item_id;
```

Comment: just remove , orders.order_date from SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the column from the `SELECT` and put the condition in a `WHERE` clause rather than a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_type, i.item_price, 
       SUM(od.order_quantity) AS `Quantity Ordered`, 
       SUM(i.item_price * od.order_quantity) AS `Total Sales Per Item`
FROM item i JOIN
     orderdetail od
     ON i.item_id = od.item_id JOIN
     orders o
     ON od.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.item_name, i.item_price, i.item_type
ORDER BY i.item_id;
```

Notes:

- The query uses table aliases, making the query easier to write and to read.
- The condition should go in the `WHERE` clause.  It is more efficient because the data is filtered *before* aggregation rather than after.
- I am not sure if `o.order_date` should be in the `group by`.  It should only go there if you want a separate row for each date.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove it from the `select` list. That won't prevent you from using it in the `where` or `having` clauses:

```
SELECT item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_type, item.item_price, SUM(orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Quantity Ordered', 
SUM(item.item_price*orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Total Sales Per Item'
-- order_date removed here
FROM item 
JOIN orderdetail ON item.item_id = orderdetail.item_id 
JOIN orders ON orderdetail.order_id = orders.order_id
GROUP BY item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_price, item.item_type
HAVING order_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
ORDER BY item.item_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include it under select is as simple as that :)

```
SELECT item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_type, item.item_price, SUM(orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Quantity Ordered', 
    SUM(item.item_price*orderdetail.order_quantity) AS 'Total Sales Per Item'  FROM item 
    JOIN orderdetail ON item.item_id = orderdetail.item_id 
    JOIN orders ON orderdetail.order_id = orders.order_id
    GROUP BY item.item_id, item.item_name, item.item_price, item.item_type
    HAVING order_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    ORDER BY item.item_id
```